# Using xpath to select both: ( text in p element ) and ( attribute 'src' in img which is child of p)

Tags: python, html, xpath

I need to extract the text and the link in attribute 'src' of element 'img' in this html

```
<div>

    <p> Line 1</p>

    <p>
        <img @src="https://example.com/abc">
    </p>

    <p> Line 2</p>

</div>
```

The output I want is:

```
# they must be in the correct order like this

[Line 1, https://example.com/abc, Line 2]
```

I tried several ways but failed:

```
xpath: //p/text() | //p/img/@src
Ouput: [ Line 1, Line 2, https://example.com/abc ]

Failed because the results were in the wrong order

xpath: //p/( text(), img/@src)
Output: xpath not valid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you want all of the leading and trailing whitespace removed (based on your expected result) and you do not want any text content from the p containing the img (you have a lot of whitespace before/after the img), then you can try an expression such as:

```
//div/p/(normalize-space(string()), string(img/@src))[string-length(.)>0]
```

Which should preserve order by combining the node and attribute string content into a sequence of atomic strings and then selecting only those strings with length greater than zero.

The normalize-space(string()) is selecting the node content of the p elements as string while eliminating leading and trailing whitespace.  The string(img/@src) is selecting the content of the src attribute of any image elements that are immediate children of p.  The [string-length(.)>0] is a predicate on the formed sequence, eliminating any strings with zero length.

Comment: Please note that my answer may require support for XPath 2+.